# Problems with custom widget in Xamarin-Studio (with Mono/C#/Gtk#)

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, xamarin-studio

I have trouble with my custom Widget in Xamarin-Studio, where I use Mono, C# and Gtk#.
It should show 2 images and 2 label, should work like a Button and should be hide-able.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using GLib;
using Gtk;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myProgram_V1
    {
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem (true)]
    public partial class myWidget : Gtk.Bin
    {
        public myWidget ()
        {
            this.Build ();
            HeightRequest = 128;
        }

        public void setHeight (int height)
        {
            HeightRequest = height;
        }

        public void setLabel1 (String text)
        {
            label1.Text = text;
        }

        public void setLabel2 (String text)
        {
            label2.Text = text;
        }

        public void setImage1 (String image)
        {
            image1.Pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf (image);
        }

        public void setImage2 (String image)
        {
            image2.Pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf (image);
        }

        [Signal ("clicked")]
        public event EventHandler Clicked {
            add {
                Signal signal = Signal.Lookup (this, "clicked");
                signal.AddDelegate (value);
            }
            remove {
                Signal signal = Signal.Lookup (this, "clicked");
                signal.RemoveDelegate (value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use this widget in the GUI-Designer of other widgets/windows like this, it is recognized by the Designer and I can set a Clickevent in the properties, but if I run the program, I get

```
(myProgram_V1:914): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2375: signal `clicked' is invalid for instance `0x7a9c9980' of type `__gtksharp_2_myProgram+5fV1_myWidget'
```

and it is not clickable.

But if I let it inherit from Gtk.Button instead of Gtk.Bin the widget is not usable with the Designer, but it can be used during runtime, if I set the click event beforehand and sometimes, during building or compiling, all global::myProgram_V1.myWidget entries in the auto generated file by the GUI-Designer are replaced with void and nothing will work anymore.

Also, .Hide() won't work with this widget and the only option to 'hide' this widget is to use .Destroy().

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please, it would be easy to help you if you provide the complete class definition, not only a partial class, without more information, I would recommend to take a look on the Gtk.EventBox class.

Comment: This is the complete content of myWidget.c#. Also I don't know how an event box should help me because it doesn't provide click events.

Comment: EventBox provides Click events, but not with the Signal "decorator".
My code: YourEventBox.Add(NotEventedWidget); YourEventBox.ButtonPressEvent += OnClick;

An then, define OnClick as : void OnClick (object sender, Gtk.ButtonPressEventArgs a) { /**/ }